# When sethook is set to an empty function, is it considerable performance hit?

Tags: lua, luajit

I'm writing small profiling library for my lua code based on hooks, because I cannot use any of the existing ones (company policies).

I'm considering if it makes sense to allow always working on-demand profiling for all of my scripts just by setting variable to true, eg.

```
function hook(event)
  if prof_enabled then
    do_stuff()
  end
end

--(in main context)
debug.sethook(hook, "cr")
```

So the question is, should I expect a significant performance hit if prof_enabled = false and hook is always set? I'm not expecting exact answer, but rather some insights (maybe, for example lua interpreter will optimize it anyway?)

I know that the best solution would be to only set the hook when it's required, but I cannot do that here.

Comment: Why not profile it and find out?

Comment: Also, since you tagged this as LuaJIT, I should mention that debug hooks don't work well with the JIT compiler. I don't think hooks are called at all in compiled code.

Comment: As an aside, consider `debug.sethook(type(hook)=="function" and hook or (function() end), "cr")` so `hook` doesn't have to be defined.

Comment: @Tom Blodget - why would that solution be better?

Comment: @Colonel Thirty Two - thx for the insight - I didn't know about the hooks not being called for compiled functions, but I noticed that the results on Jit aren't as complete. Regarding your first comment - I have actually profiled it, but obviously this depends on the software being used - on one script I got 20% performance hit, on the other I got almost nothing - so I wanted to get some insights about this (as for instance the information that this doesn't work that well on jit).

Answer (score 0):

There are ways of doing that without hook functions. One way is to replace functions of interest with a "generated" function that does profiling things (like count number of calls) and then calls the "real" function. Like this:

```
-- set up profiling

local profile = {}

-- stub function to profile an existing function

local function make_profile_func (fname, f)
  profile [fname] = { func = f, count = 0 }

  return function (...)
     profile [fname].count = profile [fname].count + 1
     local results = { f (...) }  -- call original function
     return unpack (results)  -- return results
  end -- function
end -- make_profile_func

function pairsByKeys (t, f)
  local a = {}
  -- build temporary table of the keys
  for n in pairs (t) do
    table.insert (a, n)
  end
  table.sort (a, f)  -- sort using supplied function, if any
  local i = 0        -- iterator variable
  return function () -- iterator function
    i = i + 1
    return a[i], t[a[i]]
  end  -- iterator function
end -- pairsByKeys

-- show profile, called by alias

-- non-profiled functions
local npfunctions = {
  string_format = string.format,
  string_rep = string.rep,
  string_gsub = string.gsub,
  table_insert = table.insert,
  table_sort = table.sort,
  pairs = pairs,

  }

function show_profile (name, line, wildcards)

  print (npfunctions.string_rep ("-", 20), "Function profile - alpha order",
         npfunctions.string_rep ("-", 20))
  print ""
  print (npfunctions.string_format ("%25s %8s", "Function", "Count"))
  print ""
  for k, v in pairsByKeys (profile) do
    if v.count > 0 then
      print (npfunctions.string_format ("%25s %8i", k, v.count))
    end -- if
  end -- for
  print ""

  local t = {}
  for k, v in npfunctions.pairs (profile) do
    if v.count > 0 then
      npfunctions.table_insert (t, k)
    end -- if used
  end -- for

  npfunctions.table_sort (t, function (a, b) return profile [a].count > profile [b].count end )

  print (npfunctions.string_rep ("-", 20), "Function profile - count order",
         npfunctions.string_rep ("-", 20))
  print ""
  print (npfunctions.string_format ("%25s %8s", "Function", "Count"))
  print ""
  for _, k in ipairs (t) do
      print (npfunctions.string_format ("%25s %8i", k, profile [k].count))
  end -- for
  print ""

end -- show_profile


-- replace string functions by profiling stub function

for k, f in pairs (string) do
  if type (f) == "function" then
    string [k] = make_profile_func (k, f)
  end -- if
end -- for

-- test

for i = 1, 10 do
  string.gsub ("aaaa", "a", "b")
end -- for
for i = 1, 20 do
  string.match ("foo", "f")
end -- for

-- display results
show_profile  ()
```

In this particular test I called string.gsub 10 times and string.match 20 times. Now the output is:

```
--------------------    Function profile - alpha order  --------------------

                 Function    Count

                     gsub       10
                    match       20

--------------------    Function profile - count order  --------------------

                 Function    Count

                    match       20
                     gsub       10
```

You could do other things, like time functions, if you had a high-precision timer.

I adapted this from a post on the [MUSHclient forum](http://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?bbsubject_id=10279) where I also got precise timings.

---

What `make_profile_func` does is keep a copy of the original function pointer in an upvalue, and return a function that adds one to a call count, calls the original function, and returns its results. The beauty of this is that you can omit the overhead by simply not replacing the functions with their generated counterparts.

In other words, omit these lines and there will be no overhead:

```
for k, f in pairs (string) do
  if type (f) == "function" then
    string [k] = make_profile_func (k, f)
  end -- if
end -- for
```

There is a bit of fiddling around in the code to use non-profiled versions of the functions that are used in generating the profiles (otherwise you get a slightly misleading reading).